# Importing data from unknown file format to Oracle XE

Tags: import, oracle11g, backup, datapump

I state I am new to Oracle.

I have a bunch of files named .bak they provided me as "backup files".
I have got no idea what format they are; I opened them with a text editor and discovered the first word is "TAPE" followed by binary data.

I tried to import them in my Oracle XE 11g local instance (running on Windows 11) using tools like IMP, IMPDP and RMAN but without success.

The IMP output is:
IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown

The IMPDP output is:
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-31619: invalid dump file "D:\PATH\TO\FILE\XXXX.bak"

The RMAN output is:
RMAN-07517: Reason: The file header is corrupted

Maybe they used a filesystem platform-specific format?

Anyway, how can I import data from the files?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: If the binary files were not created with with exp, expdp, or RMAN then you won't be able to import them directly. You would need the original backup tool used to create the files, restore using that (probably restoring files to an OS folder), then see whether you have anything that can be loaded into the database from there.  Without the original backup tool - or a *much* better idea how the .bak files were created - those files are probably worthless.